# How to extract a tar file (.tgz) in windows?

Tags: windows, tar, gzip

How to extract a tar file (.tgz) in windows? Is this possible, or do I have to get into a linux environment and extract it?

Comment: ....a linux environment just to extract?

Comment: I know the pain that goes behind this question: if you frequently download .tgz **whats a shortcut way to extract the content of the .tar which is inside of the .tgz.**??

Answer (score 44):

No, you don't need Linux, you can download a free tool like [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) which is more than capable of extracting `tar.gz/tgz` content.

And, on the assumption that you're writing batch files to do this extraction (since this *is* a programming site rather than a general tools help forum), it has a nice command-line interface so that you don't have to worry about GUI rubbish.

Comment: 7-zip also has a native windows x64 version.

Comment: +1 though GUI <> rubbish.

Comment: @Ulrich You can use 7-Zip Theme Manager to paint it...

Comment: @UlrichGerhardt,  Real non-GUI is using  [cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_programming_in_the_punched_card_era). As long as there's a single pixel [involved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript), it's GUI.

Answer (score 11):

[Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) contains the necessary tools, of course. It's overkill just to unpack one tarball, but if you like the Linux command line tools, Cygwin is well worth installing.

Using Cygwin you can unpack a tgz (zipped tar) file like this:

```
tar -xzf foo.tgz
```

(which means e**x**tract **z**ipped **f**ile)

You can also drag and drop the tgz file to the cygwin terminal window in order to get the path right. For drive C: it will look like this:

```
tar -xzf /cygdrive/c/the/path/to/your/file/foo.tgz
```

Comment: I have been trying to find a tar utility on windows that could extract Rocket.Chat tgz files and cygwin is the ONLY one capable of that. The archive features very long paths and links. I have tried all tools mentioned here except for WinRAR and Ch Shell and all except Cygwin's tar failed.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/) to extract `.tgz` and `.tar.gz` files however WinRAR is not a free software.

Comment: What is wrong with this answer?

Answer (score 2):

Windows has power shell.

Open power shell and type

```
tar -xzf filename.tgz
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerArchiver 6.1 (freeware) or 7-zip (freeware).

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with the previously mentioned 7zip, but you can also use WinZIP.

Answer (score 1):

I always have the [UnxUtils](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/) GNU utilities in my `PATH` on a Windows box.

UnxUtils includes `tar` and `gunzip` programs, among other things one can't live without after getting used to a Unix shell.

Answer (score 1):

Since Windows 10 version 1803 Windows includes `bsdtar` (see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows10v1803/.

`bsdtar` is available with `tar` in CMD and Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Ch Shell from SoftIntegration](http://www.softintegration.com/docs/ch/shell/unixcommands.html).

Answer (score 0):

I use [Universal Extractor](http://legroom.net/software/uniextract) I use that and 7-Zip for a lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the [gow](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki) project. It provides a nice list of Unix utilities on Win32 system. Works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have git bash installed in your machine, then run the tar command to unzip the file

```
 tar -xzf kafka-1.0.2-src.tgz
```